# 100% Stacked column chart in power bi

Tags: excel, powerbi, stacked-chart, column-chart

I have multiple columns in my sheet. for ex. my column names are- a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3, c1, c2, c3.
I want to create 100% stacked column chart where a1,a2,a3 should be in same 1 bar in chart, then b1, b2, b3 in 2nd bar of chart and c1, c2, c3 should be in 3rd bar of the chart.

What i am doing is, i selected 100% stacked column chart and selected a1,a2,a3 in y axis. Till here its working, after that when i want to put b1,b2,b3 in another bar, its not working, these values are showing in same bar. and i tried grouping, but i can't group multiple columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Power BI you need to organize your data like shown in the table on the left (aka. "stacked" table format): Split your names "a1" into a column "a" and and index "1" and so on. Then in the column chart you put "Column" on `X-axis`, Value on `Y-axis` and the "Index" on the `Legend`.

[image]

Comment: I've been frustrated with this for days, so thank you for such a clear and simple explanation. I have a follow up question: My column A data is months and the resulting chart sorts those X-Axis items by the sum of the Y-Axis values for each month and now my months on the X-Axis are no longer in order. How can I make it so the X-Axis items do not get sorted and are displayed in the order they appear in the data source?